# ASP.NET Identity: get all users in a role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How to obtain a list of all users in a role? Before it was possible with Roles.GetUsersInRole, but with new Identity I can't find anything like this.

Comment: It may be phenomenally expensive to discover the members of a role, including repeated remote queries to whatever data stores are actually supporting the identities that you're accepting - even if those stores *support* such a query. Try turning things on their head - why do you need to know all of the members of the role? (and bear in mind that as soon as your system has this information, it may be out of date)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I need to migrate an application from old Membership to new Identity. For example, I need to have a list of users in the admin role to send an email to all of them. Now I trying to imagine a database query for that and looks like it's simple query with one inner join. Maybe I'm missing a lot, but I don't understand why this is phenomenally expensive. So, I always can do this through db context, but just wonder why framework do not offer this functionality.

Comment: I said it *may* be expensive - not all scenarios for the use of the identity system have the roles stored in an SQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible via the RoleManager in 1.0 RTM, in 1.1 it will exposed via an IQueryable RoleManager.Roles.  For 1.0, you need to drop down to the implementation layer (i.e. db context)

Comment: can you explain it? give us some codes or examples. thank you

Answer (score 12):

I didn't see a built in way, but it is fairly easy to implement.  I have this method in my application specific UserManager:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
{
    return from user in Users
           where user.Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Name == roleName)
           select user;
}
```

The SQL it output seemed reasonable:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
[Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetRoles] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[RoleId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AND ([Extent3].[Name] = @p__linq__0)
)
```

Answer (score 11):

For some reason, very nice query suggested above by @ChoptimusPrime did not compile for me in ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1. I have written an extended function:

```
public static IQueryable<User> GetUsersInRole(DbContext db, string roleName)
{
  if (db != null && roleName != null)
  {
    var roles = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == roleName);
    if (roles.Any())
    {
      var roleId = roles.First().Id;
      return from user in db.Users
             where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)
             select user;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

for example if you want users list with role "User"

```
var users = await (from user in _dbContext.Users
                                 join userRole in _dbContext.UserRoles
                                 on user.Id equals userRole.UserId
                                 join role in _dbContext.Roles 
                                 on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
                                 where role.Name == "User" 
                                 select user)
                                 .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for .net core 5 and later

`var usersInRole = await new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext).GetUsersInRolesAsync("Role" );`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Entity Framework but with Asp.Net Identity 1.0 is not yet possible. You have to wait for the release of Identity 2.0.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString)) {
    string queryString = "SELECT AspNetUsers.UserName FROM dbo.AspNetUsers INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetUserRoles ON " + "AspNetUsers.Id=AspNetUserRoles.UserId WHERE AspNetUserRoles.RoleID='" + id + "'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();

    List<string> @out = null;
    dynamic reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        if (@out == null) @out = new List<string>();
        @out.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }

    return @out;
}
```

Comment: It is better to use Entity Framework with Identity then it is to drop down to SqlConnections and SqlCommands. IMO

Answer (score 0):

This is for the new `MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity`:

```
var managerRole = TMRoles.GetIdentityRole(TMRoles.Manager);
var managers = managerRole.Users;

public class TMRoles
{
    private static RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = 
        new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new TMContext()));

    public static string Manager { get { return "Manager"; } }


    public static IdentityRole GetIdentityRole(string roleName)
    {
        return RoleManager.FindByName(roleName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to get the users in any Role

```
int totalUser=db.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Name == "USER")).Count()
```